# Do Google Drive File IDs break?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm playing with the Google Drive API and one thing that I keep wondering about is IDs in the case of an arbitrary file (non-Google App) like an image.

If a user is working locally, offline and they turn off the Google Drive client. And then they make some changes to a file, let's say they rename it, move it from one folder to the next and edit it.

Will the ID remain the same when the client comes back on, or will it break? I imagine the client will interpret either one or all of the move, rename and edit as delete and new file.

Would appreciate any help here!

Answer (score 0):

The file id (within Google Drive) remains the same from the original creation to its deletion.

Comment: But would it interpret the activity as a deletion and new file? Or is there something injected into the file to track it? Or is it a 99.9% statistical thing based on a combination of block hashes, filename, path, and other OS provided metadata

Comment: Ahh OK. You're specifically asking about the Drive Sync client? I don't use it, so I don't know.